# How to load files to s3 from code commit using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I have a Glue job which will take gluescript from S3 bucket. The gluescript will be pushed to code commit and from code commit the gluescript will be automatically copied to S3.

My query is :  How to load files to s3 from code commit using Cloudformation?

Comment: How did it go with the issue? I see you posted new one. Is the current issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Other then using [AWS::CodeCommit::Repository Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codecommit-repository-code.html), there is nothing. If this does not suit you, you have to create [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation (CFN).

The custom resource would be in the form of a **lambda function**, which when triggered in CFN stack would use AWS SDK to interact with S3 and CodeCommit to copy files between the two services.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any method where we can make changes  yaml template to copy files from code commit repo to s3 bucket

Comment: @GIRIJA This requires custom solution obtained through development of a custom resource.

Comment: Thank u for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With [Cloudformation transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) you can use local paths to specify the script location. This way you can have your scripts in your Git repo and not in S3. CloudFormation will upload your scripts in the background.